# Propositional Logic with Entail Statements - Select all that are true

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus

I'm struggling to determine which are true, as the grading software says its still wrong. Ive checkmarked the ones I selected as true:

$(i)  False⊨True ✅$

$(ii)  True⊨False $

$(iii)  (A∧B)⊨(A⇔B)
 ✅ $

$(iv)  A⇔B⊨A∨B $

$(v)  A⇔B⊨¬A∨B 
 ✅$

$(vi)  (A∧B)⇒C⊨(A⇒C)∨(B⇒C) 
✅$

$(vii)  (C∨(¬A∧¬B))≡((A⇒C)∧(B⇒C)) 
✅$

$(viii)  (A∨B)∧(¬C∨¬D∨E)⊨(A∨B) $

$(ix)  (A∨B)∧(¬C∨¬D∨E)⊨(A∨B)∧(¬D∨E)$

$(x)  (A∨B)∧¬(A⇒B) $ is satisfiable.
✅

$(xi)  (A⇔B)∧(¬A∨B) $ is satisfiable.
✅

Am I missing or wrong about any? I made truth tables for several, using the idea that entails means the number of truths on the left-hand side is at most the number of truths on the right-hand side. For the last two, I used the fact that satisfiable means it's possible to get a True. I also confirmed I had the right truth tables by using a generator.

Comment: oh I was missing viii! Thank you so much @Stacker!